# unmapped memory access in array passed from python to c++

Tags: python, c++, pandas, numpy, pybind11

I am exposing a C++ class to python using `pybind11`.

It takes a `numpy.array` in its constructor, and grabs a pointer to its internal data. (*It does not copy the data*).

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Data
{
    Data(const py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style| py::array::forcecast>& arr)
        : p(arr.data())
    {
        std::cout << "arr=" << p    << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[0]=" << p[0] << std::endl;
    }
    const double* p;
};
```

I have another class which accepts a `const Data&`, thereby gaining access to the array data.

```
struct Manager
{
    Manager(const Data& data)
        : data_(data)
    {
        const double* p = data_.p;

        std::cout << "data.arr=" << p    << std::endl;
        std::cout << "data.[0]=" << p[0] << std::endl;
    }
    const Data& data_;
};
```

Here the two classes are exposed to python using pybind11:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    py::class_<Data>(m, "Data")
        .def(py::init<const py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style| py::array::forcecast>&>());

    py::class_<Manager>(m, "Manager")
        .def(py::init<const Data&>());
}
```

This is working well. I can import my module, create a `Data` instance from a `numpy.array`, and then pass that to `Manager`:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy
>>> import foo

>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data = numpy.random.rand(990000, 7))
>>> d = foo.Data(df.values)
>>> c = foo.Manager(d)
```

My script works fine, and you can see my C++ code accessing the `numpy.array` data and printing its address and first element to stdout:

```
arr=0x7f47df313010
[0]=0.980507
data.arr=0x7f47df313010
data.[0]=0.980507
```

All of the above I created in an attempt to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the problem I am experiencing below.

Now, however, I load a pandas DataFrame pickle file which I have ([here is a download link for the pickle file in question](https://files.fm/u/ykhkas2c)):

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import foo

>>> df = pandas.read_pickle('data5.pk') 
>>> a = df.values
>>> d = foo.Data(a)
>>> c = foo.Manager(d)
```

and my C++ code crashes attempting to access the array data.

Here is stdout:

```
arr=0x7f8864241010
arr[0]=7440.7
data.arr=0x7f8864241010
<dumps core>
```

So the pointer to the array is the same in `Manager`, but attempting to dereference the pointer causes a SEGV.

Running it through valgrind, valgrind reports `Access not within mapped region at address 0x7f8864241010` (ie: the address of the `numpy.array`).

Python is perfectly happy with my pickle file:

```
>>> import pandas

>>> df = pandas.read_pickle('data5.pk')
>>> df.shape
```

> ```
> (990000, 7)
> ```

```
>>> df
```

> ```
>                   A             B             C            D            E  \
> 10000   7440.695240  15055.443905  14585.542158  3647.710616  8139.777981   
> 10001   7440.607794  15055.356459  14585.454712  3647.623171  8139.690536   
> 10002   7441.155761  15055.904426  14586.002679  3648.171138  8140.238503   
> 10003   7440.430209  15055.178874  14585.277127  3647.445585  8139.512950   
> 10004   7440.418058  15055.166724  14585.264977  3647.433435  8139.500800   
> 10005   7440.906603  15055.655268  14585.753521  3647.921979  8139.989344   
> 10006   7440.525167  15055.273832  14585.372085  3647.540543  8139.607908
> ...
> ```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my pickle file.

- I have tried creating a `numpy.array` and pickling, that works fine
- I have tried creating a `pandas.DataFrame` and pickling, that works fine
- I have sliced up my "invalid" dataframe and I can get a subset which works fine

There is something in my data which python is happy about, but causes a SEGV in C++.

How can I diagnose this?

Comment: Why are you blaming the pickle?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm blaming this particular pickle file. I cannot replicate the SEGV with other data (eg: `numpy.random.rand` etc).

Comment: In addition, my python script is *exactly* the same in all ways, except in one instance I create an array of random data, and in the other I read the data from a pickle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pickle is fine. It's your code that's wrong. You take a pointer to the array's data without doing anything to ensure that that data actually lives as long as the object that uses it.

You need to keep a reference to the array and perform the associated refcount management. pybind11 probably has some sort of mechanism to represent a Python reference and handle the refcounting for you. From a quick look at the [docs](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#arrays), it looks like your code should probably take an `array_t` by value instead of const reference (as an `array_t` already represents a Python reference), and store it to an `array_t` instance variable.

Comment: Surely the fact that I have a variable `df` which is keeping the `DataFrame` alive in python is enough to keep the array from being destroyed? Or does python read ahead and know that `df` is not used afterwards, so it can speculatively delete the resources?

Comment: Note that I've created multiple other pickle files from random data and subsets of the "problem" data, and they all work

Comment: @SteveLorimer: The DataFrame is an entirely different object. `df.values` is not guaranteed to be attached to the DataFrame in any way; for mixed-dtype DataFrames, it will be a new array.

Comment: Ah I see, ok, I'll try capture a reference to the array first

Comment: I've updated the question to show capturing `df.values` in a variable first, and then passing that to my code. Same result unfortunately. In addition I would have thought if this was the cause of the problem (lifetime of a temporary) then I would see the crash happening in all my other test use cases, yet I cannot make it crash at all, only with this particular pickle (not even with other pickle files)

Comment: Oh man, I just tried your edited suggestion, and it works. Thank you so much, I've been tearing my hair out!